# kotlin coroutine switching rule?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to make two process daemons like aGroup and bGroup.
However, bGroup's never started when aGroup doesn't have `dealy` 
anyone can tell me why it happened? and what is the best way to make daemon which running forever with coroutine.

thanks

```
@Test
fun `test`() {
    runBlocking {

        val one = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            while (true) {
                runAGroup();
            }
        }.start()

        (1..10).forEach {

            async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {

                while (true) {
                    runBGroup(it)
                }

            }.start()
        }
    }
}


suspend fun runAGroup() {
    println("[AGroup] Main")
    // delay(1000L)  <--- here
}

suspend fun runBGroup(name: Int) {
    println("[BGrouop] $name (1000L)")
    delay(1000L)
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`runBlocking` without an explicit dispatcher uses an event loop to dispatch between coroutines. Because your `runGroupA` runs without interruptions there is no chance for other coroutines to run.
If you specify a other Dispatcher e.g. `Dispatchers.Default` you will see that the other coroutine runs as well.

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val one = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        while (true) {
            runAGroup();
        }
    }.start()

    (1..10).forEach {

        async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {

            while (true) {
                runBGroup(it)
            }

        }.start()
    }
}
```